# Sonarqube API server/index doesnt show correct status

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to use the `Sonarqube API` to check the status of the running instance for `healthcheck` purposes. The API call I'm using for that is `/api/server/index`. This shows the version and the status.

However, when I stop the database that the instance is connected to, the server still shows status `UP`. I feel like it should show `DOWN` instead.

Has anybody else had experiences with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue, I've created a JIRA ticket to fix it : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7001